# Replace Both Double and Single Quotes in Javascript String

Tags: javascript, replace, special-characters

I am pulling in some information from a database that contains dimensions with both ' and " to denote feet and inches.  Those characters being in my string cause me problems later and I need to replace all of the single and double quotes.  I can successfully get rid of one or the other by doing:

```
this.Vals.replace(/\'/g, "")   To get rid of single quotes
```

or

```
this.Vals.replace(/\"/g, "")   To get rid of double quotes
```

How do I get rid of both of these in the same string.  I've tried just doing

```
this.Vals.replace(/\"'/g, "")
```

and

```
this.Vals.replace(/\"\'/g, "")
```

But then neither get replaced.

Comment: Both methods work like a charm.  I will mark an answer as soon as it will let me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You don't escape quotes in regular expressions

```
this.Vals.replace(/["']/g, "")
```

Answer (score 15):

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/["']/g, "");
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to escape it inside. You can use the `|` character to delimit searches.

```
"\"foo\"\'bar\'".replace(/("|')/g, "")
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `this.Vals.replace(/("|')/g, "")`