# How to get selected columns data from json dynamically?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to get right listbox columns data from  json

[image]

My json is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "CustName": "Matt Harrison",
    "name": "Steve Rucci",
    "functionRoom": "Living Room",
    "bookingId": "659",
    "bookingName": "Matt Booking for Lost Business Report Sept 11",
    "postAs": ""
  }
]
```

I applied a customized function

```
copyObjectProps(source, keys) {
   let newObject = {}
   keys.forEach(function(key) {
     newObject[key] = source[key]
   })
   return newObject
}
```

on button click First I prepare list of Columns

```
$("#button").click(function(){
var s='';
$("Listbox > option").each(function() {
s+="'"+this.text+"',";
});
s=s.replace(/,+$/,'');
objBookingReports.RS_FN_FunctionList=s;
})
```

then this list goes to copyObjectProps() function and create filtered json object

```
var filteredparam1 = new Array();
var x =objBookingReports.RS_FN_FunctionList;

// x value is "'bookingId','bookingName'"

x = x.replace(/^"\?/, '');
x=x.replace(/"+$/,'');
var y=[x];
$.each(jsonData, function(key, value){
filteredparam1.push(objBookingReports.copyObjectProps(value,y))
});
console.log(filteredparam1)
}
```

the problem is here in formatiing . when i place column list in y=[x]; .it is not retuning json data with selected columns . but if i tried tried to place hardcore value like

```
var y=['bookingId','bookingName'];
```

then it is showing me results . please suggest how can i format my column list correctly ?

Comment: Can you please update your question with the output of the variable `x` after this line: `var x =objBookingReports.RS_FN_FunctionList;`?

Comment: this is giving me output = "'bookingId','bookingName'"

Comment: Make online code snippet and you will get fast answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
var filteredparam1 = new Array();
var x =objBookingReports.RS_FN_FunctionList;

// x value is "'bookingId','bookingName'"


// x = x.replace(/^"\?/, '');
// x=x.replace(/"+$/,'');
var y = x.replace(/["']/g, "").split(',')  // var y=[x];
$.each(jsonData, function(key, value){
    filteredparam1.push(objBookingReports.copyObjectProps(value,y))
});
console.log(filteredparam1)
}
```

It seems like that your `y` variable became a array of just one element: `"'bookingId','bookingName'"`; just try to replace the single quotes with empty space from the variable `x` and split by the comma.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760262/replace-both-double-and-single-quotes-in-javascript-string) a solution to replace the single and double quotes.